Facebook login addded new Permissions(ads_read, ads_management )
Maybe someone who has worked with Facebook login and knows how to add Permissions new( ads_read, ads_management  and so on that is related to analytics).
enter image description here
Tried to look at different settings, but all it shows is the user data, not the ads
enter image description here)

Question isn't about programming

You need to ask for them in your code, where you trigger the login. They will show up in the app dashboard afterwards, after you requested them from a user with a role in the app.
